# Error even after initializing?

Tags: c++, initialization

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float* findAverage(int arr[][1], int rows, float averages[1]);
int main (){
int myArr[1][1];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
    cin >> myArr[j][i];
    }
}
float* theAverages = {0};
theAverages = findAverage(myArr, 2, theAverages);
return 0;
}

float* findAverage(int arr[][1], int rows, float averages[1]){
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            averages[x]+=arr[i][x];
            cout << averages[0] << endl;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
    cout << float(averages[j]/2) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

^ The above is my code, but it's displaying a weird floating point number even after initializing with 0. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `int myArr[1][1];` should be `int myArr[2][2];`

Comment: I'm only averaging two rows. @mch I still get an error when printing averages[0] after I set it to 0

Comment: Then it needs to be `int myArr[2][2];`.  indices are 0 based but dimensions are not.

Comment: @mch I added that distinction, but I still get an error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems going on.

```
int myArr[1][1];
```

Is a 1 row 1 column 2d array but you are using it as a 2 row 2 column 2d array.  you need to change it to `int myArr[2][2];`.  Remember array indices start at 0 but array sizes start at 1.

The second problem is you never allocate theAverages.  You should change

```
float* theAverages = {0};
```

To

```
float theAverages[] = {0f, 0f};
```

You should also make

```
float* findAverage(int arr[][1], int rows, float averages[1]);
```

A `void` function as you are already putting the output in `averages`.  So it should become

```
void findAverage(int arr[][2], int rows, float averages[2]);
```

You will also need to get rid of the `return 0;` at the end of the function.   Then you can change

```
theAverages = findAverage(myArr, 2, theAverages);
```

To

```
findAverage(myArr, 2, theAverages);
```